# form data along with file upload with Ajax and spring

Tags: ajax, spring

i am using spring , Ajax  and trying to upload file along with other data

```
 if(form.field_UploadFile != undefined){
        formContent.field_UploadFile=$( form.field_UploadFile  )[0].files[0];
        }
   var fields ={};
   for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++){
       if (form.elements[i].name){
       if(form.elements[i].name.substring(0,6)=="field-"){
           if(form.elements[i].type=='checkbox'){
              if(form.elements[i].checked){
                   fields[form.elements[i].name]='checked';
               }else{
                   fields[form.elements[i].name]='unchecked';
               }
           }else{
                fields[form.elements[i].name]=form.elements[i].value;
           }
       }
       }
   }

   $.ajax({  
       type: "POST",  
       url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath }/forms/createnocaptcha",
       data: formContent,  
       dataType: "json",  
       contentType: false, 
       processData: false,

       complete: function (xhr, status) {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);              
            if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {
                //alert("error");
                $("#" + messagedivid).addClass("errorMessage");
                $("#" + messagedivid).html("Form sunewsbmission error");
            }
            else {
                var data = xhr.responseText;
                //$("#" + messagedivid).addClass("successMessage");
                //$("#" + messagedivid).html(data);
                $("#" + feedbackdivid).addClass("successMessage");
            $("#" + feedbackdivid).show();
            $("#" + messagedivid).hide();
            $(form)[0].reset();
            }
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forms/createnocaptcha", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createPageNoCaptcha( Form formContent, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session){
    boolean status = false;
```

If i put requestBody for formContent then  i get  415 unsupported media and if it is removed then the form values are null.

And also can I use same controller for both Multi part and non multipart.

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: I have changed my code so it makes 2 ajax call , one for adding the other data and one for uploading file . But i when i try to upload i get "The current request is not a multipart request "

Comment: function uploadFile(form){
   var formFile= new Object());
   formFile.UploadFile=$( form.UploadFile  )[0].files[0];
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath }/forms/fileUpload",
  data: formFile,
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType: false, 
           processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
                alert("file uploaded");

        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error while request..');
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

We need to convert js object to JSON string before sending it.

Change your data in ajax call like this,

```
data: JSON.stringify(formContent),
```

and then use `@RequestBody Form formContent`
And change contentType in Ajax call to application/json

Comment: If i put  stringify and RequestBody , getting 415 Unsupported Media

Comment: Use application/json as content type during Ajax call